Project must have a `ios.bundleIdentifier` set in the Expo config (app.json or app.config.js)
  iOS Bundle Identifier Learn more: https://expo.fyi/bundle-identifier
CommandError: Input is required, but 'npx expo' is in non-interactive mode.
Project must have a `ios.bundleIdentifier` set in the Expo config (app.json or app.config.js).
Error: Unknown error. See logs of the Prebuild build phase for more information.

Was getting this on eas build.

remove app.json and app.config.js from gitignore

Pleas explain what the original issue was and why this fixes it.
